# Removing final swap of Lomuto Partitioning

Tags: sorting, data-structures, quicksort, partitioning

Why cant we just avoid the final swap statement in lomuto partition just by this modification?

```
int pivot=arr[h];
int i=l-1;
for(int j=l;j<=h;j++){
    if(arr[j]<=pivot){
        i++;
        int temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
    }
}
return i;
```

Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct!.
Sorting is of two types Stable sorting and unstable sorting. Quicksort is an unstable sort because the relative position of the elements changes during partition in quicksort. if we use the following code(<=) the efficiency to maintain the relative position of the elements increases somewhat if we use your code.

```
int pivot=arr[h];
    int i=l-1;
    for(int j=l;j<=h;j++){
        if(arr[j]<=pivot){
            i++;
            int temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```